# export woff with postscript contour | how to use Sfnttool?

Tags: font-face, woff

To make font-face kit, I use the font-face generator by font squirrel : http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

But this doesn't support postscript contour and it export only woff with truetype contour. Is there a website or a programm to do it?

<-- Edit -->

A guy from Typophile told me I could use sfntly ( http://code.google.com/p/sfntly/ ) but I have absolutely no idea how to use this. Anyone knowes wehe to start with that ?

Comment: A Mac is a PC :)

(I do have both)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest method is to download the `sfnt2woff` tool from http://people.mozilla.com/~jkew/woff/

Once downloaded, open Terminal.app in OS X and drag `sfnt2woff` to the Terminal window. (This will paste the full path of the app on the command line.) It is then a simple terminal command:

```
/path/to/sfnt2woff -v 1.0 /path/to/font.otf
```

A WOFF will be created in the same directory as the font.

Comment: Great, it works ! I tryed the windows and the mac os version, they both work great (but the windows one is easier to use, you just drag the .otf file on the .exe file and it's done).